# How to return the sum of only even numbers in Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to make this loop work. Is the for/while loop a good way to return the sum of even numbers in a Fibonacci sequence?

```
   function evenFib() {
  var x, y, total;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      x = 1;
      y = 2;
    }

    while( x %2===0) {
      total = x + y;
      x = y;
      y = total;
    }

    return(total);
  }
};
```

Comment: please do not make duplicate questions, you already asked this 22 hours ago, please edit the question you already have up if you need to make changes.

Comment: The answer he got on the first question is wrong (obviously)

Comment: @sabof, that does not mean he should make another question asking the same thing and providing the same information. He should either edit his original question to clarify any questions, or wait for other answers to be posted on it.

Comment: I'm totally new here. I got flagged yesterday because I didn't ask a question. But I still need help understanding what I'm doing wrong with this problem. Should I work instead with my previous post?

Answer (score 0):

```
    function fibEven(){
        var max = 50;
        var cur = 1;
        var last = 1;
        var evens = 0;
        for(var i = 1; i < max; i ++)
        {
            var tlast = i > 1 ? cur : last;
            cur = cur + last;
            last = tlast;
            if(cur % 2 === 0)
            {
                evens += cur;   
                console.log(evens);             
            }

        }

       return evens;
    }
```

I'm not even sure how to begin explaining why your attempt is not going to work. So basically we give this a range since fibonacci is infinite. You will start getting insane numbers around 100 iterations. general rule is next number is this number plus last number. use modulus to check if there's a remainder at all. If not, add to the total evens. run this function and see.